# Hangfire.MongoDB exception: Cannot create field 'Continuations' in element {Parameters: [...]}'

Tags: mongodb, hangfire

I updated to latest Hangfire.Mongo (0.6.7) and latest MongoDB drivers (2.10.3). After the updates, some Hangfire jobs throw this exception:

```
A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors. Cannot create field 'Continuations' in element {Parameters: [ [ "CurrentCulture", ""en-SE"" ], [ "CurrentUICulture", ""en-US"" ] ]}'
```

Any attempts to start job with `BackgroundJob.ContinueJobWith` throws this exception.

This is where I traced the exception in Visual Studio:
[image]

This is the stack trace:

```
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<BulkWrite>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Hangfire.Mongo.MongoWriteOnlyTransaction.Commit() in C:\Code\Hangfire.Mongo\src\Hangfire.Mongo\MongoWriteOnlyTransaction.cs:line 400
at Hangfire.Mongo.MongoConnection.SetJobParameter(String id, String name, String value) in C:\Code\Hangfire.Mongo\src\Hangfire.Mongo\MongoConnection.cs:line 76
at Hangfire.ContinuationsSupportAttribute.AddContinuation(ElectStateContext context, AwaitingState awaitingState)
at Hangfire.Profiling.ProfilerExtensions.InvokeAction[TInstance](InstanceAction`1 tuple)
at Hangfire.Profiling.EmptyProfiler.InvokeMeasured[TInstance,TResult](TInstance instance, Func`2 action, String message)
at Hangfire.Profiling.ProfilerExtensions.InvokeMeasured[TInstance](IProfiler profiler, TInstance instance, Action`1 action, String message)
at Hangfire.States.StateMachine.ApplyState(ApplyStateContext initialContext)
at Hangfire.Client.CoreBackgroundJobFactory.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<Create>b__3(Int32 attempt)
at Hangfire.Client.CoreBackgroundJobFactory.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<RetryOnException>b__0(Int32 attempt)
at Hangfire.Client.CoreBackgroundJobFactory.RetryOnException[T](Int32& attemptsLeft, Func`2 action)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this.

I will address the bug in the github issues here:
https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo/issues/235

Answer (score 0):

We encountered something similar to this.  It boils down to how we overrode the default MongoDB Convention for how dictionaries are serialized.  This MongoDB implementation hard-codes in assumptions about how to interact with the dictionaries it creates, and if those dictionaries are not stored as the default "Document", such as an ArrayOfArrays or an ArrayOfDocuments, it doesn't work at all.

We moved on to Redis as the storage provider.